# Flask default port number

Tags: docker, flask

Am running Flask application inside a docker container, the output of the application can be seen at http://localhost:5000.

How do i make configuration for this so that the url will be http://localhost/myapp (OR) in production something like https://www.ex.com/myapp ?

Answer (score 8):

you can run application with port 80 :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

or you can use Proxy HTTP traffic to Flask through apache2/nginx.